# Can´t import SQL Server database to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I wanted to import SQL database file into PhpMyAdmin. The problem is that I get this error below. Could someone could explain me what the program doesn't like on it thanks!

Error

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

```
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "E" at position 0)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "master" at position 2)
```

SQL query:

E master

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'E master' at line 1

Open new phpMyAdmin window

Thats the code:

```
USE master ;
GO
IF DB_ID('ROM_Account') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE ROM_Account SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE ROM_Account;
END
GO
CREATE DATABASE [ROM_Account]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY
( NAME = N'ROM_Account_Data', FILENAME = N'C:\Runewaker\DATA\ROM_Account.mdf' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = 512GB , FILEGROWTH = 5%)
 LOG ON
( NAME = N'ROM_Account_Log', FILENAME = N'C:\Runewaker\DATA\ROM_Account.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 512GB , FILEGROWTH = 5%)
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [ROM_Account].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET AUTO_SHRINK ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS
GO
USE [ROM_Account]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientSystemInfo](
    [Account] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [MacAddress] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayCardVendorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayCardDeviceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OSID] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country_Filter](
    [GUID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Courty] [varchar](31) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Refuse_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country_IP](
    [GUID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IP_Begin] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [IP_End] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](31) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country_IP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount](
    [Account_ID] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount5] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount6] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount7] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount8] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount9] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount10] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount11] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount12] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount13] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount14] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount15] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount16] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount17] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount18] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount19] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount20] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount21] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount22] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount23] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount24] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount25] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount26] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount27] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount28] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount29] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleCount30] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Game_PlayerCount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Account_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MacLimitTable](
    [GUID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MacAddress] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [BanMethod] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MacLimitTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PasswordCheckRecord](
    [Account_ID] [varchar](65) NOT NULL,
    [LastCheckTime] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CheckFailedTimes] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PasswordCheckRecord_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Account_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount](
    [Account_ID] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [IsMd5Password] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAutoConvertMd5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ChargType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Point] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountState] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FreezeType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GameID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginGameID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreateTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [PlayTimeQuota] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastLogoutTime] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsInfant] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PlayTime] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstLoginTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [ValidTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserState] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Col1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Col3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Age] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [VivoxLicenseTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [ResetPassword] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FreezeUntil] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PlayerAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Account_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlayerLoginInfo](
    [index_no] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Account_ID] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [IP] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [LoginResult] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MacAddress] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PlayerLoginInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [index_no] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UidAccountMapping](
    [UID] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [Account_ID1] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [Account_ID2] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [Account_ID3] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
    [Account_ID4] [varchar](63) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UidAccountMapping] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [UID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Version](
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Version] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Version] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSystemInfo] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientSystemInfo_DisplayCardVendorID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DisplayCardVendorID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSystemInfo] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientSystemInfo_DisplayCardDeviceID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DisplayCardDeviceID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSystemInfo] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientSystemInfo_Time]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Time]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount2]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount2]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount3]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount3]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount4]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount4]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount5]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount5]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount6]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount6]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount7]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount7]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount8]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount8]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount9]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount9]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount10]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount10]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount11]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount11]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount12]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount12]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount13]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount13]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount14]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount14]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount15]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount15]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount16]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount16]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount17]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount17]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount18]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount18]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount19]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount19]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount20]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount20]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount21]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount21]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount22]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount22]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount23]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount23]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount24]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount24]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount25]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount25]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount26]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount26]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount27]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount27]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount28]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount28]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount29]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount29]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_RoleCount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Game_RoleCount_RoleCount30]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoleCount30]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PasswordCheckRecord] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PasswordCheckRecord_Account_ID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Account_ID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PasswordCheckRecord] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PasswordCheckRecord_LastCheckTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LastCheckTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PasswordCheckRecord] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PasswordCheckRecord_CheckFailedTimes]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CheckFailedTimes]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_IsMd5Password]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsMd5Password]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_IsAutoConvertMd5_1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsAutoConvertMd5]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_ChargType]  DEFAULT ((100)) FOR [ChargType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_Point]  DEFAULT ((100)) FOR [Point]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_AccountState]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AccountState]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_FreezeType]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FreezeType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_GameID]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [GameID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_LastLoginGameID]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [LastLoginGameID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_Type]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [AccountType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_CreateTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreateTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_PlayerTimeQuota]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PlayTimeQuota]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_LastLoginTime_1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LastLoginTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_LastLoginTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LastLogoutTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_IsInfant]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsInfant]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_PlayTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PlayTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_FirstLoginTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FirstLoginTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_ValidTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ValidTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_UserState]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [UserState]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_Col1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Col1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_Col2]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Col2]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_Col3]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Col3]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_Age]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Age]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_ViBoxLicenseTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [VivoxLicenseTime]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_ResetPassword]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ResetPassword]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerAccount_FreezeUntil]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FreezeUntil]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerLoginInfo] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerLoginInfo_Time]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Time]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlayerLoginInfo] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PlayerLoginInfo_MacAddress]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [MacAddress]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UidAccountMapping] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UidAccountMapping_Account_ID1]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Account_ID1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UidAccountMapping] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UidAccountMapping_Account_ID2]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Account_ID2]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UidAccountMapping] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UidAccountMapping_Account_ID3]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Account_ID3]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UidAccountMapping] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UidAccountMapping_Account_ID4]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Account_ID4]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Version] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Version_Version]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Version]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'0 Not allow this mac, 1 Ban this macaddess' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'MacLimitTable', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'BanMethod'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'帳密有效時間 (0 代表無限時間有效 )' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PlayerAccount', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ValidTime'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'保留給營運商用' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PlayerAccount', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Col1'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'保留給營運商用' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PlayerAccount', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Col2'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'保留給營運商用' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PlayerAccount', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Col3'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'0 Login 1 Logout 4 password error    其他保留' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PlayerLoginInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'LoginResult'
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ROM_Account] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is for a MySQL database and it appears you are trying to import a SQL Server database. They are completely different.

Comment: Copy/paste the error into your question rather than using an image.

Answer (score 1):

As Dale K said, you seem to be trying to import a Microsoft SQL Server database in to MySQL/MariaDB. The two flavors of SQL are not compatible with each other and you often need to do some work to massage the queries in to the other flavor.

However, try using the 'MSSQL' compatibility mode from the Import page when you're setting up the file import. By selecting that, phpMyAdmin and MySQL will try to interpret the MSSQL commands in to the MySQL variant, and it may import easily (or at least, easier).

[image: Import tab]